# I need a query that retrieves this result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of 3 columns:

- AuthorID (id can be repeated)
- JournalName (name can be repeated)
- AuthorScore

I need a query that gets JournalName and the count of all authors having their maximum score in this journal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any combination of columns that is unique?  e.g. Journal Name can repeat, but not for the same author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    maxscorejournalinstances.journalname,
    COUNT(*) as maxscorecount
from
    (
    select 
        journalname
        from
    foo inner join
        (
            select 
                authorid,
                MAX(authorscore) as maxscore
            from
                foo
            group by
                authorid
        ) maxauthorscores
    on foo.AuthorId = maxauthorscores.AuthorId 
    and foo.AuthorScore = maxauthorscores.maxscore
    ) maxscorejournalinstances
group by
    maxscorejournalinstances.JournalName
```

Note that if an author has the same high score in two or more journals, each of those journals will be included in the resultset.

Comment: It works.  The question asks for JournalName and Count of Authors with Max Score in that Journal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AuthorID, MAX(AuthorScore) as AuthorScore, 
    (
        SELECT JournalName 
        FROM tab t2 
        WHERE t1.AuthorID = t2.AuthorID AND t2.AuthorScore = MAX(t1.AuthorScore)
    ) as JournalName
FROM tab t1
GROUP BY AuthorID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   x.journalname, count(x.authorid)
from tableX x
inner join

(
select authorid, max(authorscore) max_authorscore
from tableX
group by authorid
) tmp on x.authorid=tmp.authorid and x.authorscore=tmp.max_authorscore
group by journalname
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work.

```
select authorid, journalname, authorscore, max(authorscore) over(parition by authorid)
from <table>
order by journalname
```

Doing some research on sql olap function should point you in the right direction if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need 2 queries as the data returned can not be returned in one record set where the data layout is simple to see.

The count of authors per journal,

```
select JournalName, count(distinct AuthorID) 
from table
group by JournalName
```

The author's max score per journal,

```
select JournalName, AuthorID, max(AuthorScore)
from table
group by JournalName, AuthorID
```